# Do I have access to the raw sass files using the bootstrap-rubygem gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I added the bootstrap-rubygem gem to my rails 5 application.

In my application.scss file I added:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Do I have access to the scss files that bootstrap uses?  It is possible to install them so I can manually update them?

Comment: I never did above but yes you can add your bootstrap css/js files in assets and make any change, this is what I have tried for one of my project. But in that case you need to change file extension to application.css and also make bootstrap files require in it.

Comment: It is recommended you have an overrides file that first overrides the mixins, variables in bootstrap and then you have the above import line. That way you do not need to touch the original file. In fact, that is the philosophy guiding the switch to SASS by the folks at `bootstrap`

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the scss files and you can change the variables, but the documentation is based on the latest version of `Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta.3`.

The `bootstrap-rubygem` uses different versions of bootstrap from the latest [`v4.0.0.beta3`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/releases/tag/v4.0.0.beta3) to [previous oldest alpha versions](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/tags).

As explained in the documentation this is the [files structure](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#file-structure) of the bootstrap project,

The `scss` files and partials from the [twitter-bootstrap github repository](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev/scss) are included in your [bootstrap-rubygem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/tree/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap) `assets/stylesheets/bootstrap` folder so they will probably be available to you inside your `rbenv` or `rvm` folder.

I discourage you in going into the bootstrap source to edit those files, it is discouraged in the docs itself, instead use `scss` `variables`, `functions` and `mixins` as described in their documentation

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults

I notice now that `v4.0.0beta3` is available with the [`bootstrap-rubygem`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/tags), as in my last probject I installed it with `yarn` and the files are included in `/node-modules`, but I don't really believe it is an advantage if the gem does not have bugs.